# download a zip from url and extract it in resource using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to download a zip file (my database) from a URL and extract it in specific folder (e.g. resource). I want to do it in my project build sbt file.
What would be the appropriate way to do that?
I know that sbt.IO has unzip and download. I couldn't find a good example that uses download (those I found were not working).
Is there any sbt plugin to do this for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not clear when you want to download and extract, so I'm going to do it with a `TaskKey`. This will create a task you can run from the sbt console called `downloadFromZip`, which will just download the sbt zip and extract it to a temp folder:

```
lazy val downloadFromZip = taskKey[Unit]("Download the sbt zip and extract it to ./temp")

downloadFromZip := {
    IO.unzipURL(new URL("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.zip"), new File("temp"))
}
```

This task can be modified to only run once if the path already exists:

```
downloadFromZip := {
    if(java.nio.file.Files.notExists(new File("temp").toPath())) {
        println("Path does not exist, downloading...")
        IO.unzipURL(new URL("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.7/sbt-0.13.7.zip"), new File("temp"))
    } else {
        println("Path exists, no need to download.")
    }
}
```

And to have it run on compilation, add this line to `build.sbt` (or project settings in `Build.scala`).

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(downloadFromZip)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's doing what I need , Is it possible to run this task in compile time? if the file folder was not there then download-extract and if it exist don't run the task?

Comment: This would probably motivate the creation of a plugin (if none exists) that handles the whole process: checksum, download, extract.