# Download compile and publish from within SBT Task

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a dependency on a project that is not published online, i need to download the Zip from github, compile it and publish local. So my dependency can be resolved.

Is there a way to do that with sbt. This code shows how to do the download part [download a zip from url and extract it in resource using SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466869/download-a-zip-from-url-and-extract-it-in-resource-using-sbt) but not the compile and publish part

Can anyone help or give pointer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is only to depend on a project on github you don't need to go through all of that, you can simply directly depend on that project as in this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550450/913053